# Hadoop job configuration

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Could someone explain me what's the use of configuration in the case of hadoop ?

And also explain me the following code:

```
// Create a new JobConf
JobConf job = new JobConf(new Configuration(), MyJob.class);

// Specify various job-specific parameters     
job.setJobName("myjob");

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("in"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("out"));

job.setMapperClass(MyJob.MyMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(MyJob.MyReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(MyJob.MyReducer.class);

job.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormat(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

Comment: The use really depends on what the Mapper and Reducer are doing.

Comment: Yes that's true but on a high end wanted to know what configuration really means

Answer (score 2):

> what's the use of configuration in the case of hadoop?

If I understand what you are asking correctly, then you configure a Job to know what to do when you run a MapReduce job.

You must specify input & output datatypes and locations as well as the classes that are your mappers and reducers.

Here, for example, you are taking the contents of some `"in"` directory and writing out to an `"out"` directory. Typically, these are obtained from the command line through `new Path(args[0])` and `new Path(args[1])`.

```
 FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("in"));
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("out"));
```

Here you set the respective classes for a MapReduceJob

```
 job.setMapperClass(MyJob.MyMapper.class);
 job.setCombinerClass(MyJob.MyReducer.class);
 job.setReducerClass(MyJob.MyReducer.class);
```

Here you specify the input and output format. These must correspond to the input and outputs of the mapper and reducer, respectively.

```
 job.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
 job.setOutputFormat(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

A Job also can be set with a human-readable name so you can track it in the ResourceManager.

```
job.setJobName("myjob");
```

Comment: Thanks for that !! But we define path as following:Path p1 = Paths.get("in"); Then i don't see paths there. What I studied is Path uses paths class to use their methods

Comment: I doesn't really matter how you define it, I was just saying that you typically shouldn't hardcode those values unless you always are reading in and writing out to the same directories. By using parameters at the command line, you can run the same job over any dataset.